# How to append XML data into empty lists to create dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to append XML data into empty lists to create a dataframe. I was able to create all lists besides three because some tags have null values. I have tried an xpath function to grab all the text from the desired tag.

```
import requests
from lxml import objectify
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://data.virginia.gov/api/views/xvir-sctz/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD'
response = requests.get(URL).content

import requests
from lxml import objectify


root = objectify.fromstring(response)
```

Here are some empty lists I would like to append

```
households_served = []
individuals_served = []
pounds_of_food_distributed = []
month = []
```

I tried this to give me lists, and it works.

```
pounds_of_food_distributed = root.xpath('//response/row/row/pounds_of_food_distributed/text()')
individuals_served = root.xpath('//response/row/row/individuals_served/text()')
households_served = root.xpath('//response/row/row/households_served/text()')
month = root.xpath('//response/row/row/month/text()')
```

But then I try to use pd.DataFrame with this code and I get an error.

```
table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Month': month,
     'House': households_served,
     'People': individuals_served,
     'Pounds' : pounds_of_food_distributed
    })
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me. What error messages do you see? Can you confirm that `root` has data?

Comment: I get an error when I try to create a data frame @Charles Han. It says'ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length'.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use `pandas` directly with [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), set `xpath` to all children `row` of `row` element and just slice output to your needs - This will also take care of the missing / empty elements in XML structure:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_xml('https://data.virginia.gov/api/views/xvir-sctz/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD', xpath='row//row')[['month','individuals_served','households_served','pounds_of_food_distributed']]
df.columns = ['Month','House','People','Pounds']
df
```

|  | Month | House | People | Pounds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | October | nan | nan | 156644 |
| 1 | April | nan | nan | 21602 |
| 2 | August | nan | nan | 51338 |
| 3 | May | 627 | 270 | 67633 |
| 4 | May | nan | nan | 54561 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 4254 | August | 37 | 17 | 482661 |
| 4255 | August | 1974 | 783 | 29211 |
| 4256 | April | 485 | 259 | 16254.5 |
| 4257 | August | 34986 | 8583 | 561709 |
| 4258 | June | 749 | 258 | 31560.7 |

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that some elements do not exist in the `row`, but months always exist.

One idea is to fill the missing data with 0s or anything you want.

```
import requests
from lxml import objectify
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://data.virginia.gov/api/views/xvir-sctz/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD'
response = requests.get(URL).content
root = objectify.fromstring(response)

households_served = []
individuals_served = []
pounds_of_food_distributed = []
month = []

for element in root.xpath('//row/row'):
    month.append(element["month"]) # month always exists
    individuals_served.append(element["individuals_served"] if hasattr(element, "individuals_served") else 0)
    households_served.append(element["households_served"] if hasattr(element, "households_served") else 0)
    pounds_of_food_distributed.append(element["pounds_of_food_distributed"] if hasattr(element, "pounds_of_food_distributed") else 0)

print(len(month))
print(len(individuals_served))
print(len(pounds_of_food_distributed))
print(len(households_served))

table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Month': month,
     'House': households_served,
     'People': individuals_served,
     'Pounds' : pounds_of_food_distributed
    })

print(table)
```

The output:

[image]